# join data frames for specific column

Tags: r, join

I have several data frame with format like below. I want to join/merge the data frames by `species` and extracting `kmers` from all data frames such that the out contains one column with `species` and multiple column with `kmers`, one form each of the files. The `kmers` column will then be give the name of the file from which it originated.
df1

```
reads taxReads kmers species
232 2323 23234 Bacteria
555 12 4545 Virus
```

df2

```
reads taxReads kmers species
12 23 56 Bacteria
932 1213 12 Virus
```

out

```
species df1 df2
Bacteria 23234 56
Virus 4545 12
```

I have tried making a script using join_all, but it does not select the correct column (`kmers`):

```
file_list = list.files(pattern="tsv$")    

datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){
  dat = read.csv(file=x, header=T, sep = "\t")
  names(dat)[2] = x
  return(dat)
})
joined <- join_all(dfs = datalist,by = "species",type ="full" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that you've read in the files into a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227), named by the basename of the file (with the extension removed). Naming the list-of-frames as `dfs`, we have

```r
dfs <- list(df1 = structure(list(reads = c(232L, 555L), taxReads = c(2323L, 12L), kmers = c(23234L, 4545L), species = c("Bacteria", "Virus")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)), df2 = structure(list(reads = c(12L, 932L), taxReads = c(23L, 1213L), kmers = c(56L,12L), species = c("Bacteria", "Virus")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L)))

dfs
# $df1
#   reads taxReads kmers  species
# 1   232     2323 23234 Bacteria
# 2   555       12  4545    Virus
# $df2
#   reads taxReads kmers  species
# 1    12       23    56 Bacteria
# 2   932     1213    12    Virus
```

From here, two steps:

1. Rename the `kmers` columns to the filename (sans extension), and filter out unneeded columns,

   ```r
   dfs <- Map(function(x, nm) { names(x)[names(x) == "kmers"] <- nm; x[, c("species", nm)]; }, dfs, names(dfs))
   dfs
   # $df1
   #    species   df1
   # 1 Bacteria 23234
   # 2    Virus  4545
   # $df2
   #    species df2
   # 1 Bacteria  56
   # 2    Virus  12
   ```
2. Reduce with `merge`.

   ```r
   Reduce(function(d1, d2) merge(d1, d2, by = "species", all = TRUE), dfs)
   #    species   df1 df2
   # 1 Bacteria 23234  56
   # 2    Virus  4545  12
   ```

   This could be code-golfed *here* with just `Reduce(merge, dfs)`, but I broke it out with a two-arg anon-func so that you can control some of `merge`'s options.

Comment: I got an error regarding zero length input, however, all my files should contain rows: Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot something like that when I don't have your data. Start looking at each of the frames after you read them in, for instance `all(sapply(dfs, function(z) c("kmers","species") %in% names(z)))`.

Comment: > all(sapply(datalist, function(z) c("kmers","species") %in% names(z)))
[1] TRUE

Comment: My data frames are denoted as [[1]] and  [[2]] in my datalist that reads all the data frames (dfs in your example)

Comment: I don't seem to have names of the data frames when I input them using my formula:  datalist = lapply(file_list, function(x){
  dat = read.csv(file=x, header=T, sep = "\t",check.names = F)
})

Comment: Perhaps `names(dfs) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(file_list))`?